# readfile() for video streaming?

Tags: php, file

Helllo there..

The following code simply reads out `myfile.mp4` and serves it to the client:

```
$path = "myfile.mp4";

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: ' . mime_content_type($path));
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.basename($path).'"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
readfile($path); 
exit;
```

Sadly, with files over 3GB (from what I observed), mp4 files are really hard to read.

Here is the list of problems:

1) You cant seek to the end of the video. `readfile()` will only serve your files "linearly" i'd say...

2) It takes an awful amount of time to load compared to direct, vanilla file access.

I tried looking into both the vanilla file access headers and mines and this is what I got:

```
== Vanilla apache2 file serving ==
Cause: Document

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 13 Dec 2019 05:55:42 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Thu, 12 Dec 2019 18:51:19 GMT
ETag: "9800d27f-599863b11b568"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 2550190719
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: video/mp4


Cause: Media
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Date: Fri, 13 Dec 2019 05:58:29 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Thu, 12 Dec 2019 18:51:19 GMT
ETag: "9800d27f-599863b11b568"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 9032319
Content-Range: bytes 2541158400-2550190718/2550190719
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: video/mp4
```

And here's my php script's headers (It took me 4 minutes to get them!!!)

```
Cause: Document
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 13 Dec 2019 05:57:36 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Content-Description: File Transfer
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=" - 20191126(ç«) 2330éå§ - ãã³ãã³çæ¾é.mp4"
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Pragma: public
Content-Length: 2550190719
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: video/mp4
```

I also have a "Cause: media" request apparently on this page but I didnt receive any headers from the server..

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better function to do this? Preferably a function that also let me transfer JPEG files and stuff like that...

Thanks for the read everyone!!

Comment: Maybe this previous answer will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42372831/2061685

Comment: @LeoMelin The code you linked forces the client to download the content. I'll try and set the headers to something else..

Comment: @LeoMelin Even with the headers set as something else, this code you linked only distributes files in a linear way.. I cant seek to the end of videos, for example. Also, big videos still takes alot of time to load!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried sending the file in chunks?
Also you should set the correct header like:

`header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");`

Like this:

```php
set_time_limit(0);
$file = @fopen($file_path,"rb");
while(!feof($file))
{
    print(@fread($file, 1024*8));
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
```

Also, if you are on Apache server, you should disable output compression & output buffering by adding a .htaccess file with:

`SetEnv no-gzip dont-vary`

Does this help at all?

Comment: The video loads are slightly faster (around 30 seconds), but I still cant skip to the end of a video... Sorry for the late reply! -- By directly accessing the file, the video loads in under a second.